# Automation of debugger attachment

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, sdk, automation

I have two projects, one is a "front-end" or loader project, the other is a web service, that is actually in a separate folder/solution entirely.

I'm already using my front-end, to load that project, into Cassini (there's actually two of them). What I'd like to do, is attach the debugger to both of my web services, and their associated source code, at run-time, in the front end, even those projects, aren't included in the front-ends solution.

I do have access to the source code, and the pdb's, so I believe I should be able to do this, but not 100% sure and information for doing this online is...sparse, at best.

Is there any way to do this, in .NET, visual studio SDK, or other third-party frameworks?

I have access to VS 2010 and VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a couple options here.

The first option, where applicable, is to just add the following line(s):

```
#if DEBUG
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

This will usually pop up the "Visual Studio JIT debugging" window and allow you to select a running instance or launch a new Visual Studio.

Alternatively, if you want something a bit..."trickier", you can iterate over running Processes, look for any Visual Studio instances, and bind to them using the `EnvDTE` API. This is **FAR** more complicated, so I recommend the simpler option above if it applies, but here goes:

First, we'll need a way to "find" Visual Studio instances:

```
private static IEnumerable<Process> GetVisualStudioProcesses()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    return processes.Where(o => o.ProcessName.Contains("devenv"));
}
```

Which we can then use to try attaching to the proper COM-based interfaces those running instances support:

```
private static bool TryGetVsInstance(int processId, out EnvDTE._DTE instance)
{
    var numFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
    var monikers = new IMoniker[1];
    IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
    IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;

    GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);
    runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);
    monikerEnumerator.Reset();

    while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
    {
        IBindCtx ctx;
        CreateBindCtx(0, out ctx);

        string runningObjectName;
        monikers[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, null, out runningObjectName);

        object runningObjectVal;
        runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out runningObjectVal);

        if (runningObjectVal is EnvDTE._DTE && runningObjectName.StartsWith("!VisualStudio"))
        {                    
            var currentProcessId = int.Parse(runningObjectName.Split(':')[1]);
            if (currentProcessId == processId)
            {
                instance = (EnvDTE._DTE)runningObjectVal;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    instance = null;
    return false;
}
```

Where the COM definitions are:

```
[ComImport, Guid("00000016-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleMessageFilter
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType, IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo);

    [PreserveSig]
    int RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType);

    [PreserveSig]
    int MessagePending(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType);
}
public class MessageFilter : IOleMessageFilter
{
    private const int Handled = 0, RetryAllowed = 2, Retry = 99, Cancel = -1, WaitAndDispatch = 2;

    int IOleMessageFilter.HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType, IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo)
    {
        return Handled;
    }

    int IOleMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType)
    {
        return dwRejectType == RetryAllowed ? Retry : Cancel;
    }

    int IOleMessageFilter.MessagePending(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType)
    {
        return WaitAndDispatch;
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        CoRegisterMessageFilter(new MessageFilter());
    }

    public static void Revoke()
    {
        CoRegisterMessageFilter(null);
    }

    private static void CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter)
    {
        IOleMessageFilter oldFilter;
        CoRegisterMessageFilter(newFilter, out oldFilter);
    }

    [DllImport("Ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter, out IOleMessageFilter oldFilter);
}
```

Which we can wrap up in a "Try to attach to" call like so:

```
public static bool AttachToProcess(int processId)
{
#if !DEBUG
    // Not allowed if not in DEBUG mode...
    return false;
#else
    MessageFilter.Register();
    Exception lastException = null;
    bool attachSuccess = false;
    while (!attachSuccess && !(lastException is COMException))
    {
        Log("Attempting DynamicAttach to process id:" + processId);
        try
        {
            Log("Querying for active VS instances...");
            var studioProcesses = GetVisualStudioProcesses();
            var studioDtes = studioProcesses
                .Select(proc =>
                {
                    EnvDTE._DTE dte;
                    if (TryGetVsInstance(proc.Id, out dte))
                    {
                        return new DteWrapper(dte);
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .Where(dte => dte != null);
            foreach (var studioDte in studioDtes)
            {
                attachSuccess = TryAttachTo(processId, studioDte, out lastException);
                if(attachSuccess) break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception vsex)
        {
            lastException = vsex;
        }

    }
    MessageFilter.Revoke();
    return attachSuccess;
#endif
}

private static bool TryAttachTo(int processId, DteWrapper studioDte, out Exception lastException)
{
    bool attachSuccess = false;
    lastException = null;
    Log("Attempting to attach to process " + processId);
    try
    {
        var localProcesses =
            from localProcess in studioDte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>()
            let processWrapper = new ProcessWrapper(localProcess)
            where processWrapper.Process2 == null || !processWrapper.Process2.IsBeingDebugged
            select processWrapper;
        if (!localProcesses.Any())
        {
            lastException = new ApplicationException("Can not find process to attach to!");
            return false;
        }
        foreach (var process in localProcesses)
        {
            try
            {
                if (process.Process.ProcessID == processId)
                {
                    Log("Found dte process to attach to, attempting attach...", studioDte);
                    try
                    {
                        process.Process.Attach();
                        Log("Attached to process!");
                        attachSuccess = true;
                        AtLeastOneDebuggerWasAttached = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception detachException)
                    {
                        Log("Could not attach to process:" + detachException, studioDte);
                        attachSuccess = false;
                        lastException = detachException;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception attachException)
            {
                lastException = attachException;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception queryProcessesException)
    {
        lastException = queryProcessesException;
    }
    return attachSuccess;
}
```

With some helper classes defined as:

```
internal class DteWrapper
{
    public DteWrapper(EnvDTE._DTE dte)
    {
        Dte = dte as EnvDTE.DTE;
        Dte2 = dte as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
        Debugger = dte.Debugger;
        Debugger2 = (Dte2 != null) ? Dte2.Debugger as EnvDTE80.Debugger2 : null;
        Events = dte.Events;
        DebuggerEvents = dte.Events.DebuggerEvents;
    }

    public EnvDTE.DTE Dte { get; private set; }
    public EnvDTE80.DTE2 Dte2 { get; private set; }

    public EnvDTE.Debugger Debugger { get; private set; }
    public EnvDTE80.Debugger2 Debugger2 { get; private set; }

    public EnvDTE.Events Events { get; private set; }
    public EnvDTE.DebuggerEvents DebuggerEvents { get; private set; }
}
internal class ProcessWrapper
{
    public ProcessWrapper(EnvDTE.Process dteProcess)
    {
        this.Process = dteProcess;
        this.Process2 = dteProcess as EnvDTE80.Process2;
        this.Process3 = dteProcess as EnvDTE90.Process3;
        this.ManagedProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(dteProcess.ProcessID);
    }
    public Process ManagedProcess { get; private set; }
    public EnvDTE.Process Process { get; private set; }
    public EnvDTE80.Process2 Process2 { get; private set; }
    public EnvDTE90.Process3 Process3 { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The VS API to call is [EnvDTE.Process.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.process.attach.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

The documentation of the API gives an example that attaches process by name, which does not work well with multiple application pools. You can find the correct w3wp process by application pool name via [command line tools (may require elevation)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/10/22/which-w3wp-exe-pid-corresponds-to-which-application-pool.aspx) or [w3wp command line](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jb/archive/2006/02/22/536693.aspx#10191977).